# Why :reject_if is not working in Nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using :reject_if for rejecting my field to save in DB.Here is my code

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profiles,
    :reject_if => proc { |a| a[:name] == "Name"},
    :allow_destroy => true
```

I am using nested form.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you observe (which which input), what do you expect to see? Please update your question with this.

Comment: i have nested form, i entered details in first form fields, then click add new form, the same fields are rendering using nested form.Later i click remove link in second form fields its just hide the fields,but not removing.In DB the first form fields only i want to save.For me both the fields are saving in DB.

Comment: Your example will reject all nested records from saving if name attribute of nested record equals to 'Name'. Where do you reject empty  nested records?

Comment: I tried with lambda also

Comment: @Hck: i didnt have any empty fields,i setted values for all the fields . Like :name=Name,:subject=Subject.,etc.

Comment: So, what nested records are you trying to save, and what to reject? Maybe you should check your clientside script to really remove nested form fields for records, that user removes before saving?

Comment: Hey, are you modifying the profile object in a callback like 'after_initialize' or 'after_create'?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have attr_accessible?

if so you need to include

```
  attr_accessible :profiles_attributes
```